# Brand new Monodevelop installation can't restore packages

Tags: .net-core, monodevelop, linux-mint

I'm trying to use MonoDevelop in order to work with .NET Core. In a brand new Linux Mint 20.1 machine, I installed MonoDevelop 7.8.4, and opened a project that I'm working on, and the IDE complained imediatelly:

```
Getting restore information for solution /home/REDACTED/project.sln
ApplicationName='/usr/bin/mono64', CommandLine='"/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/MSBuild.dll" "/tmp/NuGetScratch/3r24uwj4.84i.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:RestoreBuildInParallel="False" /p:RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets="False"', CurrentDirectory='/home/REDACTED', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
```

The file `/usr/bin/mono64` does not exist. Anyone knows how I can fix this?

**UPDATE**

When I try tobuild the project, it fails with the followiing error:

```
Error: NuGet packages need to be restored before building. NuGet MSBuild targets are missing and are needed for building. The NuGet MSBuild targets are generated when the NuGet packages are restored. (My.App)
```

This seems to be connected with the previous error message.

Comment: Use VSCode please.

Comment: @LexLi AFAIK, VS Code is a text editor, like Sublime Text, and not a full-fledged IDE -- or I'm wrong? Do you use it to develop in .NET Core?

Comment: If you consider the fact that MonoDevelop is half dead https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b then VSCode is anyway a better option to go. What are the IDE features you wanted? I don't see MonoDevelop offers too many more.

Comment: I need it to manage projects, solutions, NuGet packages, this kind of stuff. But I wasn't aware that MonoDevelop was half-dead. This is a dealbreaker for me, indeed.

Comment: If you need so many, then only JetBrains Rider is a feasible option today on Linux. A group of developers is out there to revive MonoDevelop, but without sponsorship they cannot make it a viable option yet, https://github.com/dotdevelop/dotdevelop/issues/42

Comment: So I'll check Rider out. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed Ubuntu and for anyone interested I found a solution.

In `/usr/bin`, make a `mono64` symlink to `mono-sgen`. `mono` is already a symlink to that.

I will investigate the other tools suggested.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31564957)

Comment: A valid point but I never claimed it to be a complete answer. From what I can tell Mono doesn't currently have the level of support it ought to have, If it did then 64 bit installations would work "out of the box" without the hack I suggested,